# How to install the dependencies

Tags: go, architecture

I am trying to create a windows service as specified [here](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/svc/example/service.go)

service.go has the following;

```
import (
    "fmt"
    ...

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/debug"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog"
)
```

So in the directory where my application is I enter the command

```
go get golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/eventlog
```

The response is

```
can't load package: package golang.org/x/sys/windows/eventlog: cannot find package "golang.org/x/sys/windows/eventlog" in any of:
    C:\Program Files\Go\src\golang.org\x\sys\windows\eventlog (from $GOROOT)

    C:\Users\Paul\go\src\golang.org\x\sys\windows\eventlog (from $GOPATH)
```

I thought "go get" was supposed to download the package. How do I get a copy onto my system so that I can run my program?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/sys#downloadinstall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check https://github.com/golang/sys what you are trying to get is src file within the repo so you have to get the whole repo to be able to get the src you need.

> It's part of a larger package